# How to select the check box on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the users tab there are some rows having check boxes. So if more than 2 check boxes are selected then a button named group appears.

Now when group button is clicked then then it will ask for a name and after pressing the ok button on the right side in the group table a group is created. For example select 1st and last row and click the group button. A dialog box appears asking to enter name. Enter test in the input field, after that in the right side group table test appears(please see the screenshot).

Now my question: is if I click the test(group name) now then on the left side the checkboxes will be selected. So in my case 1st check box and last check box will be selected. Please tell me how to do this. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/238/)

The js codes are as follows

```
$(function() { 
    $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({ 
        format: "'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'", 
        linkField: "#txt", 
        linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii", 
        autoclose: true, 
    }); 

    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){ 
        $(".darea1").val($( ".darea1" ).val()+$( "#txt" ).val()); 
    }); 

}); 
$('#tabAll').click(function(){ 
    $('#tabAll').addClass('active'); 
    $('.tab-pane').each(function(i,t){ 
        $('#myTabs li').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    }); 
}); 
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
    if(this.id=='openAlert') {
        $('#number').val('');}else{$('#number').val(this.id);
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signout").click(function() { 
        window.location.replace("logout.jsp"); 
    });
    //next line
/*var val=0;
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('#btn1').click(function(){
      if($(".span4").val()!="")
      {
  $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr'+val+'"></tr>');
  $("#mytr"+val).append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr'+val+'" checked ></td>');

             $(".span4").each(function () {

             $("#mytr"+val).append("<td >"+$(this).val()+"</td>");

              });
              val++;
      }
      else
      {
          alert("please fill the form completely");
      }
              });
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        var creat_group=confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
        if(val>1){
           alert(creat_group);


              }
    });




});*/
var val = 0;
var groupTrCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var obj={};
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
            $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
            $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" unchecked ></td>');
            $(".span4").each(function () {
                $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
            });
            var arr={};
            name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
            obj[val]=arr;
            val++;
        } else {
            alert("please fill the form completely");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
        var email=new Array();
        var username=new Array();
        var mobno=new Array();
        var grpname;
        var creat_group = prompt("Name your group??");
        grpname=creat_group;

        if (creat_group) {
            console.log(obj);
            $("#groupTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
            $tr.append("<td >" + creat_group + "</td>");
            $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
                var count=0;
                var arrid=0;
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {

                    //your ajax call goes here
                    if(count == 1){
                        username[arrid]=$(this).html();        
                    }
                  if(count==2)
                    {
                        email[arrid]=$(this).html();
                    }
                    if(count==3)
                    {
                        mobno[arrid]=$(this).html();
                    }
                    count++;
                    });
                arrid++;
            });
            $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                   data: { username: username, email: email,mobno:mobno,grpname:grpname},
                   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                       alert(data);                  
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR){
                       alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                   }
               });
        groupTrCount++;
        }        
    });
    $(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
        if(!this.checked)
        {
            key=$(this).attr('name').replace('mytr','');
            alert(key);
            obj[key]=null;
        }
//show group
if($('#mytable input:checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
        $('#btn2').removeClass('hide')
    }
    else {
        $('#btn2').addClass('hide')
    }
//
    });
});


//
        $('#openAlert').click(function(){

            var number = $('#number').val(); // If its a text input could use .text()
            var msg = $('#darea').val(); //If its a text input could use .text()
alert(msg);
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "messageSending.jsp", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { toNumber: number, body: msg},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert(data);                  
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR){
                        alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
$(function ()  
{ $("#number").popover({title: 'Enter Mobile Number',content: "Please enter 10 digit mobile number prefixed by country code eg +911234567890"});  
});  
$(function ()  
{ $("#body").popover({title: 'Message Body',content: "Maximum 160 characters allowed"});  
});
```

[image]

Comment: you want to check the checkbox once its unchecked while click the group name rite ?

Comment: You need to localize your problem and make your code more concise. There is too much code for us to understand at the moment

Comment: @rynhe yes ,I want that way

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes sure I will reduce that

Comment: post ur updated fiddle link

Comment: @rynhe please see this http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/238/

Comment: @ZachSaucier I have reduced the codes,Please have a look

Comment: @rynhe can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854538/how-to-make-automatic-adjustment-of-text-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

add `data-id` for checkbox...set the value same as `tr` `id` or any

```
<tr id="46">
       <td>
          <input data-id="46" type="checkbox"></td>
       <td>aaa</td>
```

**jQuery**

Add this lines in your code

```
var sCheckbox = new Array();
$('#mytable tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {               
     sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
var ds = (sCheckbox.length > 0) ? sCheckbox.join(",") : "";
```

Modify this line

```
$tr.append("<td data-selected='"+ds+"'>" + creat_group + "</td>");
```

Add this event

```
$(document).on('click','#groupTable tr td',function () {
        var dataids = $(this).attr("data-selected").split(",");
        $('#mytable tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked",false);
        $(dataids).each(function(key,dataid) {
               $('#mytable tr').find('input[data-id="'+dataid+'"]').attr("checked",true);
        })
    });
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rynhe/4GP9c/240/)

**Edit**

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/242/)

Add this `data-id="mytr' + val + '"` in `checkbox` element

```
$tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input data-id="mytr' + val + '" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" unchecked ></td>');
```

*note:check my inline comments in fiddle*

Comment: friend your answer is not working for dynamically added records.See there is a form which accepts name.email and mobile.when you clck on the add button then a new record gets inserted.In this case your answer is not working.Can you please tell me how to do with dynamically created rows

Comment: rows are inserting dynamically ?

Comment: In the same fiddle,In the users tab fill the form(name ,email and mobile) then click the add button.You will see new rows are geting inserted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42474/discussion-between-rynhe-and-jquerylearner)

Comment: you used data-id,please tell me when and for what purpose do we use that?

Comment: its a custom attribute

Comment: why to use?I am seeing these type 1st time,never used so sorry for asking

Comment: just for identification... u can use id instead of data-id

Comment: do you mean to say id and data-id are same?

Comment: where ever i need id i can write data-id?well so in jquery how to write means $('#').suppose if data-id=9; then $('9'),correct?

Comment: thanks again,last query are there any advantage of using data-id over id?

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813265/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined

Comment: @JqueryLearner  I will post the answer soon

Comment: waiting for your answer

Comment: The problem is solved but I have another problem,can i ask you?

Comment: I am trying to solve by this evening if not solved then I will send you mail.

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44054/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-rynhe)