# how to make automatic adjustment of text button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using twiiter bootsrap 2.6 for my web app.As you can see in the user tab of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/276/) 
This `finalhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh` causes increase of the width of the button which also increases the column  width.I want to make all the buttons of equal size and if the text length increases then the button width should not increase.The text size should automatically adjust to make the constant button width.Please tell me how to do this?

This is the html button
Please see the screenshot

[image]

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' value="finalhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" />
```

Comment: unable to see finalhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh  text anywher in your fiddle

Comment: @Sowmya, click on the USERS tab.

Comment: You can do it with little change in markup and CSS. [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9905793/473016). [Here is the fiddle with the solution in that link](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4GP9c/278/)

Comment: @anpsmn Just now I saw your comment.Well in the fiddle you have used 2 buttons why?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Oh that was just an example. Since there was a change in markup, I added a new button adjacent to the old one just to show it can be done through CSS.

Comment: @anpsmn can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834741/adding-cross-browser-jscrollpane-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to decrease font size based on text length?

If so, I recommend firstly set your button width to a fixed pixel width with css. This way your button will not jiggle.
Then on every text change you can create another button (without fixed width), set new text, measure it's width, then in loop decrease font size by a minimal unit (em vs px) until button width is within needed parameter. Then delete the newly created button and set your first button's font size to the one you've just calculated. This operation will happen really fast and user will not see it, jquery uses this trick to calculate some sizes as well.

PLEASE SEE FIDDLE IN THE COMMENTS BELOW

... But imo there are better UI solutions to this:

1. Truncate button text to max allowed characters + &hellip; and set "alt" attribute to full text.
2. Make text scroll in button right to left on mouseover.
3. Make text wrap within button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Well I am using bootsrap button classes like this `class='btn btn-lg btn-primary'` so how can I change the size.If possible please provide a fiddle

Comment: If you are using jquery you can set any css property with .css() method http://api.jquery.com/css/. As in: $(myButton).css('font-size', '12px');

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks,+1 for the fiddle

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44218/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-lex-podgorny)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in css, something like this:

```
.btn-fixed-width {
    width:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

of course, replace width with the specific width you want to use,
Add that class to the buttons you want to be fixed width
and there you have it!

Comment: still the same with your code.Well I am using bootstrap button classes *class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-fixed-width'*

Comment: you can't just add that class to your button, you also need to add the css code I posted above to a css file that is included in your website

Answer (score 0):

First get the text length by

```
var get = $("#value").val().length;
```

Then get the max size means width of button before this set a fixed width to button

```
maxScale = $("#value").width();
```

then just reduce the font size by

by comparing the both with if set the fontsize

```
if ( currentFontSize < maxSize ) {
                            currentFontSize += .1;

 $("button").css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
```

try this ...

Comment: I have edited your answer for a better look.Well can you give me a fiddle for this?